# QlineEdit::text() not returning the text entered when push button is clicked and the object name of that particular QlineEdit is lineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have created three `LineEdits` in my `Alert.ui` file. My first `LineEdit` object name is `lineEdit` from where I need to read the text when the `pushButton` is clicked. But when I checked by printing a word reach, I understood that it never enters the `onChanged` method even though the text has been changed in that `lineEdit` from blank to some value. I can't understand why this happens.

```
    import MySQLdb
    import sys
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

    qtCreatorFile = "Alert.ui"  # Enter file here.

    Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)


    class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
            QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

            self.setupUi(self)

            self.lineEdit=QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
            print("reach")

            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_clicked)


        def pushButton_clicked(self):
            self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
            self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.onClicked)

        def onClicked(self,text):

                ID=text
                print(ID)


if __name__==_main_:


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = MyApp()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your code depends on an external database and an unknown file "Alert.ui".  Can you create a self-contained example that people here can run to reproduce the problem without needing anything but the code itself and publicly available libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what's going on in your code, but from first glance I can spot the following issue:

You never connect your first QLineEdit to the `onClicked` method.

Comment: If I have many lineEdits how to uniquely identify a particular lineEdit. Can it be done by its object name. As you said I have connected how to connect it what changes should I make

Comment: How to get the text from a particular lineEdit

Comment: It depends on how many QLineEdit's you're going to create. If it's just 3 then you could assign a variable to each. If it's more you'd best be putting them in a list or something. Then you could get a particular QLineEdit by indexing: `yourList[0].textChanged.connect()`.